# Obfuscating Java code with ProGuard and Maven: Test classes and ClassNotFoundError

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, proguard

I want to obfuscate my library with ProGuard and added following piece of code into `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.pyx4me</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>proguard</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <options>
                    <option>-allowaccessmodification</option>
                    <option>-keep class mypackage.AbstractSimulationFacadeTest</option>
                </options>
                <libs>
                    <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                </libs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`mypackage.AbstractSimulationFacadeTest` is a class defined in `src/test/java`. It is used in unit tests.

When I run `mvn install`, ProGuard complains that it can't find the class `mypackage.AbstractSimulationFacadeTest`:

```
[proguard] Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'mypackage.AbstractSimulationFacadeTest'
[proguard] Note: there were 1 references to unknown classes.
[proguard]       You should check your configuration for typos.
[proguard] Error: The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper '-keep' options?
```

When I remove the line

```
<option>-keep class mypackage.AbstractSimulationFacadeTest</option>
```

and run `mvn install`, I get a `ClassNotFoundError` for `mypackage.AbstractSimulationFacadeTest`.

How should I change my `pom.xml` file so that `mvn install` runs without errors?

Comment: Is it possible that you have a reference to that class in main rather than in test?  We've seen that issue when we try and use a util class that was defined under the test package in the main source code.  This doesn't usually bite us till we make it to QA or STG since in develop it's still there but wont be in the other envs.

Comment: Nope. I just checked the references to the class and both of them are in the test part (`src/test/java`).

Comment: have you tried excluding the test package via something like        <configuration>
     <excludes>
     <exclude>test/**</exclude>
     </excludes>
    </configuration>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving to a newer version of the pro guard plugin.  You are using the default version, which is 2.0.4.  A [quick search of maven](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3a%22proguard-maven-plugin%22) shows that there is an updated version on GitHub, but under a different group id:

```
<groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
<artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.0.6</version>
```

This should get you on ProGuard 4.8, which may take care of the problem.

Also, looking at the [Pro Guard docs](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html), your -keep options should be the entry points to the artifact you are building (code in src/main/java) and not to the test cases.

Finally, it looks to me like you have moved your abstract test case from src/main/java to src/test/java at some point.  If that is the case, you may want to do a *mvn clean install* to clean up the target directory.  Pro Guard may be finding old classes from previous builds of the project.

Comment: I fixed the problem using your suggestions, but now I have another error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518872/proguard-problems-using-obfuscated-jar