# ProGuard: Problems using obfuscated JAR

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, obfuscation, proguard

I have a JAR `myapp-logic` with classes, some of which are obfuscated and some non-obfuscated.

I want to use `myapp-logic` in a web application called `myapp-web`. When I add the obfuscated version of `myapp-logic` to the dependencies of `myapp-web`, I get following error message (when I run `mvn clean compile`):

```
EntryPageController.java:[55,41] incompatible types
found   : java.lang.Object
required: ru.altruix.ccp.logic.api.simfacade.SimulationFacade
```

The code with the error looks like this:

```
final SimulationFacadeFactory factory = this.injector.getInstance(SimulationFacadeFactory.class);
simulationFacade = factory.create(); // The error occurs here (line 55)
```

When I open the obfuscated `myapp-logic` JAR with Jad, `SimulationFacadeFactory` interface is not obfuscated (or looks like it was not obfuscated):

[image]

Original code:

```
package ru.altruix.ccp.logic.api.simfacade;

import ru.altruix.commons.api.conventions.Factory;

public interface SimulationFacadeFactory extends Factory<SimulationFacade> {
}
```

Eclipse doesn't show that error (it appears only in Maven).

What can I do in order to fix the error (make the code of `myapp-web` compile with reference to obfuscated `myapp-logic`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try if that helps:
In your Proguard Rules, especially the keep Signature might help.

```
<keepattribute name="*Annotation*" />
<keepattribute name="Signature" />
<keepattribute name="Exceptions" />
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there an example of how to do it inside the `pom.xml` file (configuration of the ProGuard maven plugin) ?

Comment: I dont know  this example works for ant. But you find that easily, look at homepage for ProGuard. Let me know if that helped. The Signature is needed to be compatible with java generics.